# JQuery DataTables Plugin API - method not associated with table variable

Tags: jquery, datatable

When using [jquery.DataTables](https://datatables.net/) I run into the following problem consistently when trying to `redraw` the table from an `AJAX` source, but it also occurs with any of the [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) methods I attempt to use.

I am using version 1.10.

**Example**

```
var table = $('#table').dataTable( {
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
        ....
    },
    ajax:  'url',
    serverSide: true,
    order: [[2, 'desc']],
    stateSave: true,
    language: {
        "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
        "zeroRecords": "Nothing Found",
        "infoEmpty": "Nothing Found",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    },
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    pageLength: 10,
    lengthChange: true,
    ordering: true,
    paging: true,
    processing: false,
    searching: true
});

setInterval(function(){
    table
        .dataTable()
        .order( [[ 2, 'asc' ]] )
        .draw( false );
}, 30000);
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'order'
```

This is a copy of the [example](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) posted in the `DT` site, which the exception of the `DT` in the example passing additional parameters upon initialization.

I know the error is due to the `table` object not having the methods from `.dataTable()`, but other then that I am not sure how to get it working so that it does the `draw(false)`, or any other `API` method.

The part that gets me is that a,

```
table.fnDraw();
```

Works perfectly fine....

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    table
        .dataTable()
        .order( [[ 2, 'asc' ]] )
        .draw( false );
    }, 30000);
```

to:

```
setInterval(function(){
    table
        .api()
        .order( [[ 2, 'asc' ]] )
        .draw( false );
}, 30000);
```

Comment: this worked, thank you. I am requesting an update to the docs from Alan to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Try **SetInterval Inside Init Complete Function**, So It Won't Fire Until The Data Table Is Ready.